# Android notification keeps launching app (even when I don't tap the notification)?

Tags: java, android, notifications, alarmmanager

I'm creating a notification by extending an Activity and every time the notification appears, my app keeps launching. It doesn't launch to the same activity every time. Instead, it launches the last used activity in my app. My notification is being launched at a specific date/time through AlarmManager. How do I prevent my notification from launching my app? I need it to launch the app when the user taps on it (that part is working fine), but I don't want it to launch the app when the notification appears for the first time in the status bar. Here's my code for the notifications:

```
public class DisplayReminderNotification extends SherlockActivity {

private Context context = this;

//Grab a handle onto the database and store the name of the reminder.
protected RemindersDAO remindersDAO;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Get the notification ID.
    int notifID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("Reminder_Primary_Key");

    String reminderName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Reminder_Name");

    //PendingIntent stores the Activity that should be launched when the user taps the notification.
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ViewLocalRemindersDetail.class);
    i.putExtra("NotifID", notifID - randomInt);
    i.putExtra("notification_tap", true);

    displayIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notifID, i, 0);

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.launcher_icon, reminderName, System.currentTimeMillis());

    CharSequence from = "Here's your reminder:";

    CharSequence message = reminderName;        
    notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, from, message, displayIntent);

    //Fire up the notification.
    nm.notify(notifID, notif);

    //Destroy the activity/notification.
    finish();

} 
}
```

How do I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code after some minor modification and it is working fine at my end. Following is the code, I just changed the activity to launch with my blank activities called MyActivity:

```
public class DisplayReminderNotification extends Activity {

    private Context context = this;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get the notification ID.
        int notifID = 1234;

        String reminderName = "reminder";

        // PendingIntent stores the Activity that should be launched when the
        // user taps the notification.
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("NotifID", 123);
        i.putExtra("notification_tap", true);

        PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, notifID,
                i, 0);

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                reminderName, System.currentTimeMillis());

        CharSequence from = "Here's your reminder:";

        CharSequence message = reminderName;
        notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, from, message, displayIntent);

        // Fire up the notification.
        nm.notify(notifID, notif);

        // Destroy the activity/notification.
        finish();

    }
}
```

I made this as main launcher activity and whenever I launch this activity it only add the notification at the notification bar and it is not launching the application. I would suggest you to try this code is a separate sample app. May be the problem is at some other part of your code.